# Migration error: ENUM type already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, enums

About versions:

- Rails: 5.1.4
- PostgreSQL: 9.6.1.0

I've got two model with ENUM status, when i try to run migration for second model i get this error:

> PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  type "status" already exists :
>   CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('created', 'published', 'archived');
>   /Ruby/Projects/Apps/alpsplease/alps_app/db/migrate/20180215204243_add_status_to_experiences.rb:3:in
>   `up'
>
> Caused by: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:
>   type "status" already exists :       CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM
>   ('created', 'published', 'archived');
>   /Ruby/Projects/Apps/alpsplease/alps_app/db/migrate/20180215204243_add_status_to_experiences.rb:3:in
>   `up'
>
> Caused by: PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  type "status" already exists
>   /Ruby/Projects/Apps/alpsplease/alps_app/db/migrate/20180215204243_add_status_to_experiences.rb:3:in
>   `up' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

What's the correct way to generate same ENUM type for second model or add existing type to second model? Because creating ENUM like "status_model" doesn't looks like ideal solution.

Migration code:

```
class AddStatusToExperiences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('created', 'published', 'archived');
    SQL

    add_column :experiences, :status, :status, default: 'created', index: true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :experiences, :status

    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TYPE status;
    SQL
  end
end
```

Comment: Since Rails doesn't create Postgres enums by itself, I assume you're using some 3rd party gem to do so? Otherwise, please add the code of the failing migration to allow for a precise answer.

Comment: @ma_il I'm afraid you're mistaken. You can implemented ENUM with using the ActiveRecord::Enum module. Anyway i added migration code for you.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Enum` only works with integers or strings columns and doesn't create database-specific types.

Comment: @ma_il Yes. As you can see, i'm using strings. More over, if you add enum to model you can call status like: `experience.published?`

Comment: You're not using strings, but a custom enum type via separate `CREATE TYPE` statement. The important thing is to differentiate between what's happening in Ruby and on the database side. Adding an enum to your model class will not in any way influence the migration. And the migration in turn doesn't know about the enum so it can't auto-create a custom type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a `status` enum type from your previous model, the solution is extremely easy and straightforward: just specify the type as `:status` and you're good to go. No additional `CREATE TYPE` or `DROP TYPE` in the migration.

Just know that if you modify the enum type, all tables using it will of course be influenced in the range of possible values. Nonetheless, here's a tip in case you want to add a new value at some point: you need to disable database transactions for that. I.e.

```
class AddNewStatus < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction! # enums cannot be altered from within a transaction

  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TYPE status ADD VALUE 'foobar';
    SQL
  end
end
```

For more information about sharing enum types, see this post:
[Share enum declaration values between models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451169/share-enum-declaration-values-between-models)

In case you don't want to share the type (i.e. they just incidentally have the same name but a different set of possible values), you can rename the existing type via `ALTER TYPE status RENAME TO experience_status` and issue another another `CREATE TYPE` with a second name as you did before, referring to the new type for the column of the second table.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. But this way appear worse than duplication with similar name :)

Comment: I'll explain to you why. If my main model will need new status, this decision be an issue. In any case, thanks is again.

Comment: Can you add this way to your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451169/share-enum-declaration-values-between-models